# Как записать числа в массив через promt и как позже проводить с ними мат. операции?

Tags: javascript

Не могу разобраться как мне через один Промт записать в массив сразу несколько чисел( Пример: 3, 5, 6,....) и убрать у них запитые. Так же если я пишу знак '-' первому числу так же дается знак '-' как это поправить и выходит '-2 - 2 = -4'?

```
let action = prompt('C каким знаком вы хотите выражение?')
let pr=[];
let sum = 0;

while (action!== '+' && action!== '-' && action!== '*' && action!== '/') {
    action = prompt('C каким знаком вы хотите выражение?');
}

for(let i = 0; i<2; i++) pr.push(prompt('1'));

for(let i = 0; i < pr.length; i++){
    pr[i] = +pr[i]

        switch (action) {
            case "+":
                sum += pr[i];
                break;
            case "-":
                sum -= pr[i];
                break;
            case "*":
                sum *= pr[i];
                break;
            case "/":
                sum /= pr[i];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
}
alert(sum)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const string = prompt("numbers?") // Вводим числа через запятую: 1, 3, -5, 12, -7, 0
const numbers = string.split(',').map((item) => +item()); // Получаем массив чисел из строки
console.log(numbers) // [1, 3, -5, 12, -7, 0]
```